# What is the estimated ROI for someone who bought in before 2010?

Tags: buy-bitcoins

As the title asks, what kind of profits were available for those people who were lucky enough to have found out about Bitcoin prior to 2010? Or when it began?

Comment: Well, there's the guy who bought [two pizzas for 10,000 BTC](http://www.coindesk.com/bitcoin-pizza-day-celebrating-pizza-bought-10000-btc/). A lot has changed since then.

Comment: It's hard to answer because in those days, there weren't enough people trading bitcoin for other currencies to establish a meaningful market price.